# How to use single image for UISplitviewController navigation bar image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uisplitviewcontroller

In my app i want to have a single image to cover both the Master and Detail view controller's navigation bar.
I tried doing this in AppDelgate by setting UISplitviewController navigationItem.title view but it did not work.

Any suggestions ??

This is the code in AppDelegate didFinishLaunching Method

```
UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;

    UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[0];
    BAMasterViewController *controller = (BAMasterViewController *)masterNavigationController.topViewController;
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    return YES;
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Do you want a single navigation bar to cover the whole width of the screen? Which controllers will be pushing new controller onto the navigation stack? Master? Detail? Both? Do you just want a single background image (across both controllers), but still 2 navigation bars, so you get the correct animation when either controller does a push or pop?

Answer (score 0):

`UINavigationBar` has the following method:

`- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage forBarMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics`

Use that.

Comment: I know. But the problem is i can only set it for one of the view controllers of the UIsplitViewController.

Comment: Are you seeing the problem when you open the popover?

Comment: My app is Landscape mode only.

Comment: Then setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics should work, I do the same in my project.

Comment: Do you mean one image to cover both navigation bars? That is not possible. You have two navigation bars. If you wish to remain with one image, and since you are with landscape support only, you can chop your `UIImage` proportionally to the two bars' sizes.

Comment: Yeah. i am keeping that option open. But in the meanwhile looking for some other solution too because in that case the divider line would be visible.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40599/discussion-between-leo-natan-and-ashutosh)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to style your navigation bar with appearance method:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:];
```